# Android autoCompleteTextView don't find first part of first adapter string

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I've added autoCompleteTextView to my activity.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewSearch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/zxing_status_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/toolbar2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/toolbar2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar2" />
```

Then I've added code to MainActivity.java in onCreate:

```
String[] arrayData = {
        "30714518   Tyre Bycicle 14\"x2.125 ORNATE 518  2000289537714   190 300 2   1",
        "30718827   Tyre Bycicle 18\"x1.75 DURO 827 2000289544736   170 350 0   4",
        "307275161-1    Tyre Bycicle 27,5\"x2.10 CHAOYANG 5161  2000289537813   400 650 1   3",
        "30710590   Tyre Bycicle 10\"x2.0 H-590 CHAOYANG    2000289557941   170 300 0   5",
        "30718518   Tyre Bycicle 18\"x2.125 ORNATE 518  2000289537745   220 400 1   9",
        "30716518   Tyre Bycicle 16\"x2.125 ORNATE 518  2000289537721   200 350 1   114",
        "30718888   Tyre Bycicle    2000289537721   200 350 1   114"
};


ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, arrayData);
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteWidget = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextViewSearch);
autoCompleteWidget.setThreshold(1);
autoCompleteWidget.setAdapter(adapter);
```

What's going on when I start my app and type text in the autocompleted field:

1. "30718" - I see results
2. "30714" - **there are no results**
3. "20002895377"- I see results
4. "By" - I see results
5. "DURO" - I see results.

Why when I type 30714 there no results?

I tried to change the 1st string and every time there no results when I try to find the first phrase of the 1st string.

Comment: Since it is your first question on SO, you might read [the guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

How is your `dataFromFileInList` get created?

If your adapter data is from `arrayData`, it should works like the code below.

```
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_text_view);

    final String[] arrayData = {
            "30714518   Tyre Bycicle 14\"x2.125 ORNATE 518  2000289537714   190 300 2   1",
            "30718827   Tyre Bycicle 18\"x1.75 DURO 827 2000289544736   170 350 0   4",
            "307275161-1    Tyre Bycicle 27,5\"x2.10 CHAOYANG 5161  2000289537813   400 650 1   3",
            "30710590   Tyre Bycicle 10\"x2.0 H-590 CHAOYANG    2000289557941   170 300 0   5",
            "30718518   Tyre Bycicle 18\"x2.125 ORNATE 518  2000289537745   220 400 1   9",
            "30716518   Tyre Bycicle 16\"x2.125 ORNATE 518  2000289537721   200 350 1   114",
            "30718888   Tyre Bycicle    2000289537721   200 350 1   114"
    };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, Arrays.asList(arrayData));
    autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
This mistake appear when I copy code here. Adapter get **arrayData** (String array, not List). But the problem is still here.